# Network manager misses my network card

Tags: networking, network-interface, networkmanager, vpn

I've got the following network card:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 12d1:1506 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Modem/Networkcard
```

It's accessable through `ip` tool and properly works with `dhcpcd` (3rd entry in the output below):

```
$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp5s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:3a:84:84 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wwp0s18f2u1i1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:5b:8f:27:9a:64 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.8.100/24 brd 192.168.8.255 scope global wwp0s18f2u1i1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::48d6:a9ee:6db4:1236/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

But `NetworkManager` seems to ignore it:

```
$ nmcli device show
GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp5s0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         BC:5F:F4:3A:84:84
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
```

I can continue using `dhcpcd` for this connection, but I need to connect to `VPN` sometimes, and `NetworkManager` is not allowing me to establish `VPN` connection unless it's ensured I have `LAN` connection.

Answer (score 0):

Change in /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf  `[ifupdown]
managed=false` to `[ifupdown]
managed=true`

Comment: There was an empty config, I've tried to add `[ifupdown] managed=true` and it has no effect. I've also tried to add only `managed=true`, and this leads to not starting NM service.

Comment: t was emty?  The whole file looks like this. `[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false`  in original.

Comment: I've got this:
`# Configuration file for NetworkManager.
# See "man 5 NetworkManager.conf" for details.`